# Set which part of a string is displayed in a WPF combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to set which part of a string is displayed in a WPF comboBox when the string is too long to be displayed in full?

For example, I have a string "my very long string" which, when selected, is truncated to "my very l". I would like to display "long string" instead.

I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a binding specified, you can use a value converter that considers the length of the string, and if it is greater than a value then it trims the string and adds "..."